# Firefox: How to resize "Add bookmark folder" window?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, size

Right-clicking on the Bookmarks Toolbar and selecting "Add Folder..." shows the "Add bookmark folder" window.

[image: How do you to increase the window width?]

I am using Firefox 107.0.1/Latest version (Windows).

How do I resize the window?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resizable` attribute is set to false for that element. To override this, you can modify it in [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/).

```
.dialogBox[resizable="false"] {
    resize: both !important;
}
```

[image: Screenshot showing resizeable window]